# Return two variables in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

At the moment here is what im doing

```
ret=$(ls -la | awk '{print $3 " "  $9}')
usr=$(echo $ret | awk '{print $1}')
fil=$(echo $ret | awk '{print $2}')
```

The problem is that im not running an `ls` im running a command that takes time, so you can understand the logic.

Is there a way I can set the return value to set two external values, so something such as

```
ls -la | awk -r usr=x -r fil=y '{x=$3; y=$9}'
```

This way the command will be run once and i can minimize it to one line

Comment: Parsing `ls` should be punishable by death. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: like i said im not actually parsing `ls` its just there as an example to get my point accross. Sorry i didnt make that clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround using `read`

```
usr=""
fil=""
while read u f; do usr="$usr\n$u"; fil="$fil\n$f"; done < <(ls -la | awk '{print $3 " "  $9}')
```

For performance issue you could use `<<<`, but avoid it if the returned text is large:

```
while read u f; do usr="$usr\n$u"; fil="$fil\n$f"; done <<< $(ls -la | awk '{print $3 " "  $9}')
```

A more portable way inspired from @WilliamPursell's answer:

```
$ usr=""
$ fil=""
$ while read u f; do usr="$usr\n$u"; fil="$fil\n$f"; done << EOF
> $(ls -la | awk '{print $3 " "  $9}')
> EOF
```

Comment: I still like this way better, Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's not pretty, but if you really need to do this in one line you can use `awk`/`bash`'s advanced meta-programming capabilities :)

```
eval $(ls -la | awk '{usr = $3 " " usr;fil = $9 " " fil} END{print "usr=\""usr"\";fil=\""fil"\""}')
```

To print:

```
echo -e $usr
echo -e $fil
```

Personally, I'd stick with what you have - it's much more readable and performance overhead is tiny compared to the above:

```
$time <three line approach>

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.011s

$time <one line approach>
real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Comment: +1 Very good approach. But how could we update your code to allow `$usr` and `$fil` contain the list of all users and all filenames? (this first version gives solely the last user / filename).

Comment: Hi @bob, I have just changed your code to catch all the users/files, not only the last pair. Please, could you perform again your benchmark? Now, the time results should be comparable...

Comment: Thanks - misunderstood the original req! Have updated based on oHessling's excellent edit (with a minor tweak). Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is capture the output of ls or any other command and then process it later.

```
ls=$(ls -l)
first=$(echo $ls | awk '{print $1}')
second=$(echo $ls | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` v4 **associative array**:

```
unset      FILES
declare -A FILES
FILES=( ls -la | awk '{print $9 " "  $3}' )
```

Print the list of owner & file:

```
for fil in ${!FILES[@]}
do
  usr=${FILES["$fil"]}
  echo -e "$usr" "\t" "$fil"
done
```

My apologies, I cannot test on my computer because my `bash` v3.2 does not support **associative array** :-(.
Please, report any issue...

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer uses process substitution, which is a bashism that only works on certain platforms.  A more portable solution is to use a heredoc:

```
read u f << EOF
$( ls ... )
EOF
```

It is tempting to try:

```
ls ... | read u f
```

but the read then runs in a subshell.  A common technique is:

```
ls ... | { read u f; # use $u and $f here; }
```

but to make the variables available in the remainder of the script, the interpolated heredoc is the most portable approach.  Note that it requires the shell to read all of the output of the program into memory, so is not suitable if the output is expected to be large or if the process is long running.

Comment: +1 Yes you are right => I have then completed my answer. Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a bash array or the positional parameters as temporary holding place:

```
ret_ary=( $(command | awk '{print $3, $9}') )
usr=${ret_ary[0]}
fil=${ret_ary[1]}

set -- $(command  | awk '{print $3, $9}')
usr=$1
fil=$2
```

Comment: Most elegant solution**s**, using either `set` or `array[]`